# How to suppress the ExportedCommands output from Exchange powershell script output

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to get some information from exchange online 2016 using powershell script. Here I'm using this script

```
$UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
$ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $ExchangeSession -DisableNameChecking
```

and I'm getting following output:

**ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

---------- -------    ----                                ----------------

Script     1.0        tmp_avadkvxn.tjc                    Get-MailboxUsageReport**

My question is,
I don't want this above message in my output. how to suppress this? I want only the exact output. Here I didn't mention the command what I have used. While trying to import the session its giving this information message in console, how to suppress this

Thanks in advance,

Arul

Comment: Can any one help me pls

Comment: `Import-PSSession` returns module object. It should be enough to redirect result of that command, e.g. `$null = Import-PSSession ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use import command as below.

**This will work:**

`$null = Import-PSSession`